# Interchange limit and supremum

Tags: calculus

I simply don't get the following question answered:

How can i proof the equality $\lim_{a\to 0}\sup_{z\in\mathbb{Z}}2-2\cos(2\pi a z)=0$?

Or is it even false?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is wrong.

If $a$ is rational, then $\cos(2\pi az)$ will take the value $-1$ at some $z$. Hence, for $a\in \mathbb{Q}$, you have 
$$\sup_z(2-2\cos(2\pi az)=4.$$

Since you can go arbitrarily close to zero with rational numbers, the limit cannot be zero...

Comment: taking the sequence $a_n=1/2n$. Then for every $n$ the supremum equals to 4 (z=n), so that the limit is 4, for this special sequence.

Comment: Yes. Hence, the general limes cannot be zero.

Answer (score 0):

Think little bit differently.

$2 - 2\cos(2\pi a z) = 2(1-\cos(2 \pi a z)) = 4\sin^2(\pi a z)$$

Now in complex plain $\sin(z)$ is an unbounded function having a zero at origin. So the value of the expression should be $0$.

Comment: For $z$ fixed you are right. But what if you take first $\sup$ in $z$?

Comment: Sorry i dont see why this yields, that my limit should be zero?